# PHP Script is no longer fixing Datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have the following PHP script that takes a poorly formatted date column and then writes it into a datetime column.

The data looks like this:

```
Tail_Number,Departure_Date,Departure_Date2,Departure_Time,Arrival_Date,Arrival_Date2,Arrival_Time,Original_Airport,Destination_Airport

N681GH,14-Jun-15,,1701,14-Jun-15,,1808,KFHB,KPDK
```

The end result is that the Date2 fields end up with the default 0000-00-00 00:00:00 instead of actually combining the date/time as they had previously.

The script was working fine but now suddendly is not updating my datetime field but I can't tell what is wrong as the month seems the same?

```
$sql = "SELECT *, Date(Departure_Date2) As Dep2 FROM faaData0707new WHERE  Departure_Date2 = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
echo $sql;

$q = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if (!$q) {
        die("query error: ".mysql_error($conn)."<br>in query: <pre>$sql</pre>");
}

$x = 0;
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($q)) {



        $sDepTime = $obj->Departure_Time;
        $sDepDate = split("/",$obj->Departure_Date);
        $sDepMonth = "";
        if (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "JAN")
            $sDepMonth = "01";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "FEB")
            $sDepMonth = "02";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "MAR")
            $sDepMonth = "03";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "APR")
            $sDepMonth = "04";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "MAY")
            $sDepMonth = "05";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "JUN")
            $sDepMonth = "06";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "JUL")
            $sDepMonth = "07";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "AUG")
            $sDepMonth = "08";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "SEP")
            $sDepMonth = "09";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "OCT")
            $sDepMonth = "10";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "NOV")
            $sDepMonth = "11";
        elseif (strtoupper($sDepDate[1]) == "DEC")
            $sDepMonth = "12";


        $sArrivalTime = $obj->Arrival_Time;
        $sArrivalDate = split("/",$obj->Arrival_Date);
        $sArrivalMonth = "";

        if (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "JAN")
            $sArrivalMonth = "01";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "FEB")
            $sArrivalMonth = "02";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "MAR")
            $sArrivalMonth = "03";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "APR")
            $sArrivalMonth = "04";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "MAY")
            $sArrivalMonth = "05";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "JUN")
            $sArrivalMonth = "06";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "JUL")
            $sArrivalMonth = "07";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "AUG")
            $sArrivalMonth = "08";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "SEP")
            $sArrivalMonth = "09";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "OCT")
            $sArrivalMonth = "10";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "NOV")
            $sArrivalMonth = "11";
        elseif (strtoupper($sArrivalDate[1]) == "DEC")
            $sArrivalMonth = "12";




        $sNewDepartDate = $sDepDate[2]."-".$sDepMonth."-".$sDepDate[0]." ".substr($sDepTime,0,2).":".substr($sDepTime,-2);
        $sNewArrivalDate = $sArrivalDate[2]."-".$sArrivalMonth."-".$sArrivalDate[0]." ".substr($sArrivalTime,0,2).":".substr($sArrivalTime,-2);

        $sql = "UPDATE faaData0707new Set Departure_Date2 = '".$sNewDepartDate."', Arrival_Date2 = '".$sNewArrivalDate."' WHERE PK = ".$obj->PK;
        #echo $sql;
        mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die("query error: ".mysql_error($conn)."<br>in query: <pre>$sql</pre>");;




        $x++;   




}

echo "fixed ".$x." rows";
exit(0);
```

Comment: From PHP Manual. `split(): Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.` [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

Comment: @craig_h - that is the data raw, sorry...I will update the question.  The output simply updates the *2 columns with the default 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and never inserts the correct values.

Comment: You already echoed the query. How does the generated UPDATE Query look like?

Comment: You can replace the whole elseif block with a single line: `DateTime::createFromFormat( "d-M-y", $obj->Departure_Time );`, then use `$dateTime->format()` to get the date in the format you need.

Comment: Hmmm, curious...@GeraldSchneider it echo as UPDATE faaData0707new Set Departure_Date2 = '--14-Jun-15 93:37', Arrival_Date2 = '--14-Jun-15 11:06' WHERE PK = 65

Comment: Well, it looks like your split isn't working, as Jay suggested. And while you fix that, you can replace the also deprecated `mysql_*` functions as well.

Comment: LOL, yeah...this thing is a freaking mess.  It's been around since 2004 I think at least.  I guess it's time for a rewrite.  The split changed to a -.  I updated it and also switched out to an explode works great.  Thanks for the help, Bless The Stack!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce a lot of your code to a few lines:

```php
$sql = "SELECT *, Date(Departure_Date2) As Dep2 FROM faaData0707new WHERE  Departure_Date2 = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
echo $sql;

$q = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

$x = 0;
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($q)) {

        $Departure_Date = DateTime::createFromFormat( "d-M-y Hi", $obj->Departure_Date . " " . $obj->Departure_Time );
        $Arrival_Date = DateTime::createFromFormat( "d-M-y Hi", $obj->Arrival_Date . " " . $obj->Arrival_Time );

        $sNewDepartDate = $Departure_Date->format( "Y-m-d H:i:00" );
        $sNewArrivalDate = $Arrival_Date->format( "Y-m-d H:i:00" );

        $sql = "UPDATE faaData0707new Set Departure_Date2 = '".$sNewDepartDate."', Arrival_Date2 = '".$sNewArrivalDate."' WHERE PK = ".$obj->PK;
        #echo $sql;
        mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die("query error: ".mysql_error($conn)."<br>in query: <pre>$sql</pre>");;

        $x++;   
}

echo "fixed ".$x." rows";
exit(0);
```

Alternatively, you can do it a lot easier directly in MySQL:

```sql
UPDATE faaData0707new 
SET Departure_Date2=STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Departure_Date,' ',Departure_Time), "%d-%b-%y %H%I") 
WHERE Departure_Date2 = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

This will create a single string containing both the date and the time (`CONCAT()`), extract the date and time from it (`STR_TO_DATE()`) and write them directly into the row again. Not a single line in PHP nessecary.

Answer (score 1):

you split the Departure_Date by '/' (see line

```
$sDepDate = split("/",$obj->Departure_Date);
```

but in your db you have this date with '-', see:

```
14-Jun-15
```

and same with Arrival_Date. So you work with empty array items, not with items from your date

Btw, isn't this cleaner solution?

```
$oldDate = strtotime($obj->Departure_Date);
$sNewDepartDate = date("d-m-Y", $oldDate);
$sNewDepartDate .=  " " . substr($sArrivalTime,0,2).":".substr($sArrivalTime,-2);
```

Comment: Thanks, split was deprecated too as mentioned in the comments.  I changed to explode and it worked as well.  It should also be mentioned the entire mysql_* functions are deprecated.